# MBROLA voices with FreeTTS - Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, text-to-speech, freetts

**Using MBROLA voices in a Java program with FreeTTS...**

I am working on a simple *text-to-speech* program in Java. I have decided to use FreeTTS, but the voices are not really what I was thinking, and I was looking to use a female voice anyway. So I started looking around, and decided that I would use MBROLA to change the voice of my *text-to-speech* program.

I read that ***"FreeTTS can use MBROLA voices"***, but I searched everywhere and couldn't find a clear guide how to set MBROLA up, and what files are needed to do so. There are many forums on MBROLA working alongside FreeTTS, however it also seems that none of the people have any idea what they are doing.

**So the questions:**

1. *What files need to be downloaded?*
2. *Steps to include these into my program?*
3. *Simple FreeTTS example using MBROLA voices?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Answers to the questions above:**

***1. What files need to be downloaded?***

1. **FreeTTS** with all the libraries *(freeTTS 1.2.2-bin)* - [download here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freetts/files/FreeTTS/FreeTTS%201.2.2/freetts-1.2.2-bin.zip/download)
2. **MBROLA** zip folder *[mbr301d.zip](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/bin/pcdos/mbr301d.zip)*
3. **Voices** which can be found on the [MBROLA website](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html)

1.1 The **FreeTTS** libraries *(found in freetts-1.2.2-bin/freetts-1.2/lib)*:

- cmu_time_awb.jar
- cmu_us_kal.jar
- cmudict04.jar
- cmulex.jar
- cmutimelex.jar
- en_us.jar
- freetts.jar
- freetts-jsapi10.jar
- mbrola.jar

1.2 The **MBROLA** zip folder will include:

- mbrola.exe
- mbr302a *(folder)*
- readme.txt

1.3 The **Voices** are zipped folders that include a single folder named '**us1**' or '**af1**' etc.

---

***2. Steps to include these into my program?***

**NOTE:** I had the [MBROLA Tooklit](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola.html) installed on my computer too, however I am unsure whether it has an impact on the program, but I suspect that it doesn't. EDIT: I have tested to see whether the MBROLA toolkit is needed to run MBROLA alongside FreeTTS, and it turns out that it is not needed.

1. Extract freetts-1.2.2-bin
2. Copy the libraries to your project and include in build path
3. Unzip the mbr301d.zip folder
4. Rename 'mbr301d' to 'mbrola'
5. Unzip the voices to the folder you named 'mbrola'

After this is done, your mbrola folder should look like this:

- [mbr302a] - *folder*
- [us1] - *folder (name depends on the language you downloaded)*
- mbrola.exe - *file*
- readme.txt - *file*

You can place all your languages in this folder, and they will just be called from your Java program.

---

***3. Simple FreeTTS example using MBROLA voices?***

I've seen many people get this error:

```
System property "mbrola.base" is undefined.  Will not use MBROLA voices.
```

The `mbrola.base` refers to where your mbrola files are located on your computer, and without the property being pointed to the correct location, you will recieve this error.

**To NON-MBROLA users who get this error:** Simply remove the mbrola.jar from your referenced libraries if you're only using FreeTTS

To set the `mbrola.base` property, use:

```
System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "C:/Path/to/your/mbrola")
```

Below is a simple Example to use the MBROLA voices in your FreeTTS program. Note that the steps above must be done before this will work. Simply changing the name of the voice to "mbrola_us1" will not work if the base isn't set!

```
package com.madmob.test;

import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;

public class TestTTS {
    VoiceManager freettsVM;
    Voice freettsVoice;

    public TestTTS(String words) {
        // Most important part!
        System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "C:/mbrola");
        freettsVM = VoiceManager.getInstance();

        // Simply change to MBROLA voice
        freettsVoice = freettsVM.getVoice("mbrola_us1");

        // Allocate your chosen voice
        freettsVoice.allocate();
        sayWords(words);
    }

    public void sayWords(String words) {
        // Make her speak!
        freettsVoice.speak(words);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        new TestTTS("Hello there! Now M BROLA and Free T T S work together!");
    }
}
```

MBROLA and FreeTTS should now be working together! This code was copied right from my computer and has been tested before putting it down here.

Comment: I have been made aware that some of the other languages from MBROLA do not work, however it seems that the English versions do. I will look into it and see if I can somehow fix it. I shall edit the answer to support all of the voices, or add notes where neccessary.

Comment: I got that to work! The MbrolaVoiceDirectory class is a bit evil, it suppresses error messages such as when the mbrola binary is not found. I patched that, then I could fix my remaining problems. I wasn't aware that the mbrola binary is needed at first. (Nobody has ported that to Java, right?)

Comment: BTW I had to add this line: `System.setProperty("freetts.voices", "de.dfki.lt.freetts.en.us.MbrolaVoiceDirectory");`

Comment: Also, international voices will not work, right? MbrolaVoiceDirectory checkes only the 3 US voices.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to responses on this forum, I was finally able to make it working.
On windows 10; I carried out following steps to make it working:

1. Download freeTTS libraries and include them in my Java project in eclipse.
2. Download [mbr301d.zip](http://tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/bin/pcdos/mbr301d.zip), extract it in a folder named mbrola within my project
3. Download mbrola database for us1, us2, us3 and en1 from http://www.tcts.fpms.ac.be/synthesis/mbrola/mbrcopybin.html
4. extract the voice DB zips downloaded in previous step directly in mbrola folder - don't change names of the folders.
5. include following code pieces to use it:

   ```
   System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO_mbrola_directory_ending_with_/");
   voiceManager = VoiceManager.getInstance();
   voice = voiceManager.getVoice("mbrola_us1");
   ```

   Note: **if your voice DB folder name is us1; then you should add it above as "mbrola_us1"; if it is en1, then it should be "mbrola_en1"**. This actually has done the trick for me.

Comment: Can I use a relative path to mbrola folder as I want to include the whole folder in jar file for distribution purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Please find working example from here:

https://github.com/sunrise-projects/sphinx4/tree/glass

```html
package com.sunriseprojects.freetts.demo;

import java.beans.PropertyVetoException;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.speech.AudioException;
import javax.speech.Central;
import javax.speech.EngineException;
import javax.speech.EngineStateError;
import javax.speech.synthesis.Synthesizer;
import javax.speech.synthesis.SynthesizerModeDesc;
import javax.speech.synthesis.Voice;

public class SpeechUtils {
 SynthesizerModeDesc desc;
 Synthesizer synthesizer;
 Voice voice;

 public void init(String voiceName) throws EngineException, AudioException,
   EngineStateError, PropertyVetoException {
  if (desc == null) {
   //default
//   System.setProperty("freetts.voices",
//     "com.sun.speech.freetts.en.us.cmu_us_kal.KevinVoiceDirectory");
   
   //have to be setup
   System.setProperty("freetts.voices",
     "de.dfki.lt.freetts.en.us.MbrolaVoiceDirectory");
   desc = new SynthesizerModeDesc(Locale.US);
   Central.registerEngineCentral("com.sun.speech.freetts.jsapi.FreeTTSEngineCentral");
   synthesizer = Central.createSynthesizer(desc);
   synthesizer.allocate();
   synthesizer.resume();
   SynthesizerModeDesc smd = (SynthesizerModeDesc) synthesizer
     .getEngineModeDesc();
   Voice[] voices = smd.getVoices();
   Voice voice = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < voices.length; i++) {
    if (voices[i].getName().equals(voiceName)) {
     voice = voices[i];
     break;
    }
   }
   synthesizer.getSynthesizerProperties().setVoice(voice);
  }
 }

 public void terminate() throws EngineException, EngineStateError {
  synthesizer.deallocate();
 }

 public void doSpeak(String speakText) throws EngineException,
   AudioException, IllegalArgumentException, InterruptedException {
  synthesizer.speakPlainText(speakText, null);
  synthesizer.waitEngineState(Synthesizer.QUEUE_EMPTY);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  System.setProperty("mbrola.base", "C:\\lnx1\\home\\ggon\\git-projects\\mbrola");
  SpeechUtils su = new SpeechUtils();
  
  //have to be setup on your env
  su.init("mbrola_us1");
  
  //default
  //su.init("kevin16"); 
  //su.init("kevin");
  //su.doSpeak("Hello world!");
  su.doSpeak(SAMPLE);
  su.terminate();
 }
 
 final static String SAMPLE = "Wiki said, Floyd Mayweather, Jr. is an American professional boxer. He is currently undefeated as a professional and is a five-division world champion, having won ten world titles and the lineal championship in four different weight classes";
}
```