# Freetts: how to run freetts code in java using maven

Tags: java, maven, freetts

*Hello guys ! I'm develop an application like to Jarvis but issue is that when i paste freetts code in my application, maven throws exception but when i do as discuss in tutorial [http://moderntone.blogspot.com/2013/02/freetts-tutorial.html] then everything fine*

```
 CMULexicon: Oh no!  Couldn't find lexicon data!
  Error: Can't load voice java.io.IOException: Can't load lexicon
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Can't load voice 
  java.io.IOException: Can't load lexicon
  at com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice.error(Voice.java:875)
  at com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice.allocate(Voice.java:326)
  at com.mycompany.mehrunisa.Mehrunisa.speak(Mehrunisa.java:20)
  at com.mycompany.mehrunisa.Mehrunisa.main(Mehrunisa.java:34)
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  BUILD FAILURE
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Total time: 1.758s
  Finished at: Tue Apr 24 21:25:16 PKT 2018
  Final Memory: 5M/109M
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec 
  (default-cli) on project Mehrunisa: Command execution failed. Process 
  exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) -> [Help 1]
  To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e 
  switch.Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.**
```

Comment: The problem is related to this: `Command execution failed. Process 
  exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)`

Comment: how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: How should I know. You have the code....

Comment: you can check code , visit here https://github.com/AlihassanProgrammer/Mehrunsia

Comment: Problem solve [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27808248/java-freetts-missing-voice/50019509#50019509]